# When I use ARKit's ARSCNView, can I use the iPhone's front camera?

Tags: iphone, swift, camera, arkit, arscnview

Currently I am learning about ARKit.
On the Internet, there are usually sample code that uses ARSCNView and iPhone's back camera.
I would like to use ARKit with a front camera instead of an iPhone's back camera.
When I use ARKit, can I use ARSCNView and iPhone's front camera?
Does ARKit support both iPhone's front camera and back camera?
Also, could you tell me if you have sample code that uses ARKit, ARSCNView and iPhone's front camera?

Comment: Can you add code for back camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it does exist, it is still a bit limited as the only devices capable of running it are those that have a TrueDepth front camera, which is only the iPhone X so far.

There is sample code from apple that allows it that can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences

And here is a reference to a list of cameras supported by device: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH107-SW1